# Update wrong excel cell using ado.net

Tags: excel, ado.net

I am updating excel cells by using Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 Library.

and this is my update statement

```
"UPDATE [" + sheetName + "D5:D5"] SET F1 = 201";
```

But in excel CELL D1 is updated. am not getting why Cell D1 updated instead of Cell D5.

My connection string is

```
public static string path = @"C:\src\RedirectApplication\RedirectApplication\301s.xlsx";
public static string connStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;";
```

I am using .Net Framework 1.1

Windows : Windows XP

Any Idea?

Answer (score 0):

Put a "$" at the end of your sheet name.